# Order of sourcing scripts

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings, runtimepath

I've recently been organizing my `vimrc` and putting mappings into `vimfiles/plugin` and `vimfiles/ftplugin` files (not to mention abbs, functions and commands).

However, these scripts are sourced *before* default scripts (See `:h rtp` & `:help ftplugin-overrule`) and any e.g. mappings can get clobbered by default mappings.

The latter help's only viable suggestion is to put these files into the `vimfiles/after` dir. But given that there's no way of knowing without checking all default scripts for mapping etc that might overwrite user mappings etc, it would seem that the user's `plugin`, `ftplugin` dir are useless. And that I need to put *everything* into the `after` dir. Any maps etc put in these user's dirs just might be unexpectedly overwritten by default scripts.

For example, I have `vimfiles/ftplugin/html.vim` with mapping `<C-b>`. This is overwritten by default `html.vim`. If I put latter mapping in `vimrc` it too is overwritten.

If I have a mapping in `vimfiles/mapping.vim` that is the same as any of the default scripts *later* sourced it is overwritten.

Am I showing ignorance of something here? I'm tempted to change the `runtimepath` to put my scripts after default scripts. But maybe there's a good reason that, say, default `html.vim` script is sourced after (is more important than) my `html.vim`?

Comment: I cannot find a mapping for `<C-B>` in `html.vim` - or anywhere else in `$VIMRUNTIME`. Can you specify your Vim version and the exact location of these mappings? Maybe you will find `:help ftplugin`, especially the section titled `DISABLING`, helpful.

Comment: Anecdotally I use (in addition to vimrc) `~/.vim/after` for all filetype stuff (syntax, indent, ftplugin) to customize anything coming from defaults, plugins, etc. For compiler scripts, colorschemes, ftdetect, etc., I use `~/.vim`. And I use `~/.vim/vimrc`

Comment: I should mention that it would be an anti-pattern for a Plugin (in the sense of something you distribute to others via, say, Git) to use after directories unless it absolutely had to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason that the user `ftplugin` is sourced early is so you can *entirely replace* the runtime's file with your own. In order to do so, you need to set the `b:did_ftplugin` in your copy to prevent the runtime's ftplugin being loaded.

If you look at [the top of `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/html.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/d086b8f646a67f6b16c46061ce773de1011b8ec7/runtime/ftplugin/html.vim#L7), you'll see the lines:

```
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
  finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```

This means that if you set `b:did_ftplugin` in `~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim` the runtime's file will exit immediately.

The purpose of the `after` directory is if you *do* want some of its settings and just want to override some of these or add some of your own.

For the documentation on this, see the `Note` in item 1 of [:help ftplugin-overrule](https://vimhelp.org/filetype.txt.html#ftplugin-overrule), and items 2 and 3. (You can ignore the stuff about making a copy of Vim's file: it's only the setting of `b:did_ftplugin` that determines whether or not the runtime file will be loaded.)

Answer (score 2):

When you speak of mappings being overridden, and even of putting mappings either in the vimrc or in ftplugin files, I'm wondering something. I'll address this doubt, to be sure.

Are the mappings you store in your ftplugin files defined as buffer-local? Everything that goes into ftplugin files shall be buffer-local (except for functions, but functions should go into autoload plugin files). This means:

- mappings and abbreviations are annotated with `<buffer>`
- commands need the `-b` parameter
- menus require [plugin support](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-misc/blob/master/autoload/lh/buffermenu.vim)
- variables shall belong to `b:` namespace/scope
- vim options shall be local-options set with `:setlocal`

Anything else that smells *global* doesn't belong to ftplugin files. And nothing local can be set in the vimrc or in other plugin/autoload plugin files without passing through an autocommand.

---

Also, I have [plenty ftplugins files](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/tree/master/ftplugin). None of them being in the after directory, and none of them setting `b:did_ftplugin`. That's because they define stuff that are unlikely to conflict with default ftplugin files.

This also leaves room for users of my plugins to put things in the `after` directory to adjust settings, or in their own `~/.vim/ftplugin` directory to prevent my scripts from being loaded.

---

Anyway, I confirm what other have said.

- Either put your mappings in the `after` directory
- Or set `b:did_ftplugin` to prevent standard/default ftplugin files from being loaded -- but then, nothing from them will be set.

And don't forget: everything that goes into ftplugin files shall be buffer-local.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for such problems is indeed the `after` version of these script.

e.g:`~/vimfiles/after/ftplugin/html.vim`

If you want to override the default you have to put you settings in `after`.

I would not say `~/vimfiles/ftplugin` is useless in general. Vim use a generic runtime path system and executes the scripts of `ftplugin` in the order of the runtime path and then the script of `after/ftplugin` in the same runtime path order.

Comment: How can I ever be sure that what I put in `vimfiles/plugin` or `ftplugin` will not be overwritten by defaults? And I would've thought that user files would take precedence over defaults.

Comment: If you put it in `vimfiles/ftplugin/` they will be overridden but if you put it in `vimfiles/after/ftplugin` they will not since the default has no `after`. The propose of after is precisely to give the user the possibility to override the standard (aka default).

Comment: Apologies if I'm being irritatingly persistent but, what's the point of the `vimfiles/ftplugin` and 'vimfiles/plugin` folders if one can never be sure they'll not be overwritten by defaults.

Comment: No problem your question is very valid. It is my answer that is not clear enough. The way Vim is coded is very generic and rooted in the history of Vim. All the folder in `runtimepath` can have the same structure with the various subfolders `plugin`, `ftplugin`, `after\ftplugin`, ... and they are visited in the order of the `runtimepath` order for each category (generic code). It is up to the user to use it they way they want. In particular it is indeed a common practice in the `vimfiles` entry to not use the `ftplugin` entries and to only use the `after/ftplugin` entries